# How get value from url in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to get value but it not working. below is my url I want to get `1` from url as number

> https://localhost:44300/Portal#/user-edit/1

```
constructor(private router: Router,
    private userService: UserService) {

    this.router
        .routerState
        .queryParams
        .subscribe(params => {
            this.id = params['id'];
        });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should inject **ActivatedRoute** to get ***route params*** as shown below,

```
constructor(private router: Router,
    private userService: UserService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,) {  //<----- here

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.id = +params['id'];   //<----- + sign converts string value to number
});
```

read more here : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#route-parameters

Comment: How about using `route.snapshot.params['id']` ?

Comment: @kds23 if the id doesnt change (i.e. clicking on next button that displays another product without reinitializing the component) then you can use `route.snapshot.params`. But it's generally safer to use an observable.

Answer (score 1):

Awesome reply! Just an add-on:

The property names have been updated. Use `paramMap` instead of `params` and `queryParamMap` instead of `queryParams`

See https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route

An example:

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }
    ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
        console.log(params.get("id"));
    })
}
```

See this link for the available methods:
https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap