# How to get parameter from URL(Routing) Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I tried to do that in `ngOnInit()` like:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams
      .filter(params => params.type)
      .subscribe(params => {
        this.tab = params.type;
        this.setHeader();
      });
  }
```

My URL is:

```
http://localhost:4200/s/6/t/p/create/1
```

Routing is:

```js
{path: ':Id/t/p/create/:type', component: CalendarComponent},
```

Comment: You have 6 params in your url and five in the routing. Check that to start with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How get value from url in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39364225/how-get-value-from-url-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try that  :

```ts
this.route.snapshot.params["page"]
```

the page is the query param so the route must be like that

```ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'page/:page',
    component: OrdersComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Orders'
    }
  }
]
```

don't forget the add the route into the constructor

```ts
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
```

and the import

```ts
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";
```

Comment: if you want use the Observable : 
`this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => this.page = +params['page']; );`

Comment: Why `page` inside  this.route.snapshot.params["page"]?

Comment: `this.route.snapshot.params` it's an array of all query params so to access directly the param page use this.route.snapshot.params["page"]

Comment: for your case change it by type

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.tab = params.type;
    this.setHeader();
  });
```